# Heroku Telegram bot deploy error on Java (Maven), package doesn't exist

Tags: java, maven, telegram

Terminal, deploy on Heroku:

```
remote:        [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[5,38] package org.telegram.telegrambots.bots does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[6,50] package org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[7,55] package org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[8,50] package org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[9,50] package org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_51434ea5/src/main/java/com/deputatBot/DeputatBot.java:[10,49] package org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions does not exist
```

pom.xml, Maven. TelegramBots library was added from Maven's website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>deputatBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>deputatBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    // here were spring dependencies
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>Bots</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    //here were spring plugins

</project>
```

Project builds fine on my machine, but fails when deploying on Heroku. TelegramBots library is added to Maven.

Comment: post your project's POM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, just needed to change this library to a https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).